# Rotating bitmap from URL using Picasso library

Tags: android, picasso

I need to display images using Picasso library, keeping the original orientation.
I'm taking pictures using Camera or from Gallery, and then upload multiple images to server using Volley.

The problem is when images are loaded, they are rotated, i.e. orientation is wrong.

How can I rotate images in both portrait or landscape mode loaded from server?

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("http://:www..." + url).into(imageView);
```

I tried to get *exif* orientation from images on server using PHP *exif_read_info*, but Orientation is not specified.

Comment: Check this one https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-image-rotation-and-transformation

Comment: This solution will only work if images are rotated 90 degrees, what about 0, 180 and 270?

Comment: Am not sure that the problem is with picasso, did u checked the server that the uploaded image is in correct orientation

Comment: No, images on server are not in correct orientation, that's the problem.

Comment: `No, images on server are not in correct orientation,` You mean original orientation. Well than do not mention Picasso. Do not blame Picasso. Blame Volley. And inspect the upload. Or upload different.

Comment: I know Picasso is working fine, but as I said, I'm using Picasso to display images. I cannot upload different, this is exactly what I want. That's not solution for the problem... My question is HOW to display images correcty.

Comment: If the problem is with file upload, then there is no use of asking questions related to picasso, Ask new question with volley file uploading code.

Answer (score 1):

```
To rotate by 90 degree use.
Picasso  
    .with(context)
    .load("http://:www..." + url)
    .rotate(90f)
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know exactly if needed rotation is 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees.

Comment: can you explain the scenario under which you want to rotate the Image. if you want to rotate based on Mobile tilt.. then you can get the tilt angle from the accelerator and calculate the tilt angle.

Comment: Images are loaded from server into ListView, some of them are rotated correctly, others are rotated for 90 or 180 degrees, even upside down.
[i.e. this image should not be rotated this way](http://www.atterobay.com/public/upload_images/invoice_files/original/=google-rotated.png). I want to rotate images so they are all in correct orientation (image above should be rotated 180 degrees).

Comment: There is no Orientation tag in PHP exif_read_info:
[link to exif info](http://imgur.com/a/fRwW8)